Regularisation properties with the (not squared) L2 penalty
I have been looking for sources regarding the regularisation properties of the L2 norm penalty in a linear regression setting. By that I mean e.g., shrinkage properties, when the L2 norm is used as a penalty, and not the squared L2 norm (so I'm not talking about ridge regression). The problem I am thinking about is the following:
$$
    \min_{\beta} \frac{1}{n}\|y - X\beta\|_2^2 + \lambda\|\beta\|_2,
$$
where $\beta$ is a real vector, $X$ is a real matrix, $y$ is a real vector, and $\lambda$ is a positive real scalar.
Does anyone know of any good sources with discussions about regularisation properties of this problem?

Based on a cursory search you may in fact be asking about a rescaled ridge regression, with the caveat that only the squared norm is guaranteed to be differentiable.

I found the duplicate by searching for lasso square* penalty, finding one duplicate at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289434 with a link-only answer, and following that link.  You might find other hits in that search to be instructive, too.

By Lagrange multiplier arguments, the Ridge objective is equivalent to a constrained problem $\min_{\beta, |\beta|^2\leq C} |y-X\beta|^2$, where $C$ depends on $\lambda$ (i.e. the regularization term becomes a constraint). In the same way, your objective is equivalent to $\min_{\beta, |\beta|\leq C'} |y-X\beta|^2$ where $C'$ is some other constant that depends on $\lambda$. Since $|\beta|\leq C'\Leftrightarrow |\beta|^2\leq C'^2$, the geometric forms of the constraint sets are identical, and the only difference is the way that they are parametrized in terms of $\lambda$.
This means that the solution to your problem with a fixed $\lambda$ is equal to a Ridge solution with some other value $\lambda'$ and vice versa, so effectively your problem is just Ridge with the dependence on $\lambda$ being reparametrized.
